# Get string len of char ptr at compile time

Tags: c, string

I would like to get the string length during compile time.

I know if I have a static string I can do it like this here:

```
char string[] = "Hello World";
int len = sizeof( string ) - 1;
```

This will give me the same output like strlen.

But is this also possible for a char ptr?

```
char const * string = "Hello World";
int len = sizeof( string ) - 1;
```

This gave me as len 7, because I get the sizeof the type. strlen gave me the correct during runtime, but I would like to optimize code during compile time.

Comment: About performance, is that really such a bottleneck in your code that you need to micro optimize it?

Comment: No, it is not possible. You can define a macro for the initializer string though and take its `sizeof`

Comment: I have a lot of string compares in my code. @EugeneSh. What do you mean?

Comment: `#define MYSTRING  "Hello world"` then `char const * string = MYSTRING` and then you can take `sizeof(MYSTRING)`

Comment: Remembering that literal strings are really arrays, you can use `sizeof` on the literal string itself (as in `sizeof "Hello World" - 1`). But if all you have is a pointer to a single character in a string, that's all you have and you can't get the length at compile-time in a standards-compliant way.

Comment: Okay thanks. We can close this request I think.

Answer (score 0):

The contents of pointers are subject to change, so the compiler cannot make any assumptions about the length of the string, so you cannot get the length with `sizeof`. If you want to use pointers, you must get the string length with `strlen`.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a helper macro:

```
#define DEF_STRINGVARS(ptrvar, lenvar, literal) \
    const char *ptrvar = "" literal ""; \
    int lenvar = sizeof "" literal "" - 1;
```

Note:

The `""` before and after `literal` is just to make the compiler produce an error if it does not expand to a string literal. (There are devious ways to defeat the check if you try hard enough.)

Usage:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DEF_STRINGVARS(ptrvar, lenvar, literal) \
    const char *ptrvar = "" literal ""; \
    int lenvar = sizeof "" literal "" - 1;

int main(void)
{
    DEF_STRINGVARS(hello, len, "Hello World")

    printf("%s %d\n", hello, len);
}
```

Output:

```
Hello World 11
```

Note that the length does not take into account any null characters in the string literal. For example:

```
DEF_STRINGVARS(hello, len, "Hello\0World")
```

will initialize the `len` variable to 11, not 5.